# How to calculate cumulative field values in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new to *JasperReports* and *iReport*, and I am facing a problem. Before going through the question, first, please take a look at the following image:

[image]

So, the main problem is with the cumulative columns. Per say, the "Cumulative Bill" column should show the following values sequentially:

6000.0, 14000.0, 23000.0, 32800.0, 42800.0 and 45800.0

I have no idea how this can be done. I tried creating a new variable, but there is no cumulative type calculations there. Please assist me.

Comment: I am not new to Jasper Report, but I don't know how to archive this (if Jasper can do it?). However if it's possible, I am interested in the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Create variable $V{variableName} with calculation = Sum and Variable expression = $F{BillAmountField} and put text field with this variable into detail section.

Is it so hard? :)

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I have already tried this before. Here is the declaration in case I am wrong:


`<variable name="CUMULATIVE_BILL" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="None" calculation="Sum">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{billAmount}]]></variableExpression>
  <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0.0]]></initialValueExpression>
 </variable>`

I assigned the variable as the field expression in the details band.

Comment: Found the solution! The following code works perfectly:

`<variable name="CUMULATIVE_BILL" class="java.lang.Double" resetType="Report" calculation="Sum"> <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{billAmount}]]></variableExpression> <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0.0]]></initialValueExpression> </variable>`

Comment: You are welcome.  Mark my aswer as useful, please :) AFAIK initialValueExpression for double default = 0.0   But resetType="Report" is right choice.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at the query level, here is the query :-

```
SELECT m.bill_amount,
       @cbill:=@cbill+ifNull( m.bill_amount,0) cumulative_bill
FROM (
      SELECT @cbill:=0,
             bill_amount
       FROM 
      )m
```