# ireport quires set for the SQL for Set query?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to get equivalent query for the Ireport.
this is my sql query.
but when I am pasting it to Ireport dataset i am getting this error.

```
set @csum := 0;
set @csum1 := 0;
select SUM,(@csum := @csum + Profit_Total) as Cumulative,
Sum(profit) as Profit_Total
from table t1;
```

Comment: Questuin is unclear. What is c1? Which data you want select? Show example.About cumulative values see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273613/how-to-calculate-cumulative-field-values-in-report

Comment: @sanBez I have edited the question. let that c1 be the Total Profit in the table T1

Comment: @sanBez The SQL query is working fine. I want a same query for Ireport or jasper Server. any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this way, first try to set the variables in inner select statement then you can sum up in the outer select statement :-

```
    SELECT SUM(@csum := @csum + Profit_Total)
    FROM (SELECT profit, @csum := 0
          FROM  t1) a;
```