# dynamic variable value jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I don't know how to title this question and I know it's just a simple and stupid logic need to be sorted out but I can explain what I need. I have a jasper report script and query in which I need a simple calculation based on a value gathered from Query below

```
SELECT TOTAL, PARTIAL FROM PRICE WHERE TOTAL > 0
```

now I need this value to be calculated as the expression below in jasper report script

```
VAR CALC += TOTAL + (PARTIAL) //as partial can be a -ve or +ve value
```

What's happening currently is that I didn't find a way to do this, whenever I assign value of `TOTAL` to a variable and try to use it, it always get's the value from Query and calculates, while I need it to be there only once and then perform calculation on it onward. For that I tried to use `calculation="First"` but that also gives the first value for all the time and continues. I hope I am able to put my problem well, please help

**EDIT**

***QUERY***

```
SELECT RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATE,
       TICKETS.TICKETID AS TICKETID,
       PAYMENTS.PAYMENT AS PAYMENT,
       PAYMENTS.METHOD AS METHOD,
       PAYMENTS.TOTAL AS TOTAL,
       CUSTOMERS.NAME AS NAME,
(SELECT SUM(P.TOTAL) FROM PAYMENTS AS P
    INNER JOIN RECEIPTS AS R ON P.RECEIPT = R.ID 
    INNER JOIN TICKETS AS T ON R.ID = T.ID 
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS AS C ON T.CUSTOMER = C.ID 
    WHERE C.ID = CUSTOMERS.ID and P.PAYMENT IN ('debt','debtpaid', 'advance', 'cashrefund')) AS CTOTAL
    FROM RECEIPTS
          INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
          INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
          INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
    WHERE   
          PAYMENTS.PAYMENT IN ('debt', 'debtpaid', 'advance', 'cashrefund')
....
....    
WHERE -TOTAL > 0
```

***VARIABLE***

```
<variable name="DUES" class="java.lang.Double" resetGroup="Customer" resetType="Group" calculation="Nothing">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{CTOTAL} + $F{TOTAL}]]></variableExpression>
        <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new Double(0.0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

***OUTPUT***

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example of data returned by the query and how the variable value should change with each row?

Comment: as I explained above the data returned is simple double values, which I need to be used as `value = value + anotherVal;` so in a sense the value variable will be changed on each row of report accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can define the variable itself in SQL statement like this :-

```
   SELECT SUM(@csum := @csum + TOTAL+PARTIAL)
   FROM (SELECT TOTAL, PARTIAL,@csum := 0
         FROM PRICE WHERE TOTAL > 0 
         ) a;
```

[See this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533282/ireport-quires-set-for-the-sql-for-set-query/23608917#23608917)

Comment: Are you sure that it would work in jasper report, as there always is a new value for the variable on each row?